# Infinitive Phrase or Verb Constituent

Tags: phrases, verbs, nouns, modal-verbs, infinitives

I refer to *Doing Grammar* by Max Morenberg as my default grammar reference.

Morenberg makes a distinction between infinitive phrases, which function as Noun Subjects & Objects (SC, NDO, etc), and infinitives that are part of a verb phrase:

I **want to see** the evidence (1 verb phrase, want is a modal)

I agreed **to watch the boy**. (noun phrase, functioning as Direct Object)
I asked **to see the evidence**. (noun phrase, functioning as Direct Object)

How do you distinguish between verb phrase constituent and a separate noun phrase?

Comment: Aside from Morenberg's claim, how does one distinguish one kind from the other? All those infinitives are functioning as objects. Claiming that _want to see_ is different from _asked to see_ because _want_ "is a modal" is not a useful criterion.

Comment: Infinitival clauses don't function as objects -- only noun phrases can do that. In all of your examples the infinitival clauses are not functioning as object but as **complement** of the verb concerned. Your examples are commonly called catenative (chain) constructions, the kind where certain verbs have non-finite clauses as complement. @KannE please note.

Comment: @KannE Note that this is BillJ's opinion and terminology, not mine. I use the terms the way McCawley does; he uses the terms the way CGEL does. These are not ISO standards, understand, and they're not "commonly called" by everybody; they are technical terms, and they overlap to a large extent, sort of like Slavic languages -- if you're a native speaker of one, you can understand most of the others. While shaking your head at the unnecessary complexity of some morphological or phonological systems, of course.

Comment: Many infinitival clauses can be interpreted with a meaning like that of an NP, but we're talking syntax here, and "to see ..." / "to watch" ..." have the form of a clause, not an NP. Incidentally, the same argument applies with the so-called 'noun clauses' / 'adjective clauses'. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal syntactic form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: It's not an argument to say that X is true because X "has the form of a clause". It's an opinion about forms and designations. How about a syntactic test for a syntactic term?

Comment: And we wonder why youngsters are not interested in grammar!

Comment: I don't. They're not interested in it because they never encounter it. Who would teach them?